# Entering US on B1/2 visa after previous residence under TPS (Temporary Protected Status)

Tags: usa, us-visa, b1visa, b2visa

Main Questions: Should a person who held TPS previously have any concerns with returning to visit the US on a B1/2 visa to visit family?

Background info: This person lived in the US for 20 years under TPS protection. They moved abroad, have a job, apartment, etc. and applied for and received a B1/2 visa. This person was upfront with their history at their visa interview, and answered all questions truthfully. The consular officer was obviously satisfied that the applicant has no immigrant intent, will this help also satisfy the CBP officer? Or is their bar a little higher?

TPS Explainer from DHS:

> What is TPS The Secretary of Homeland Security may designate a foreign
> country for TPS due to conditions in the country that temporarily
> prevent the country's nationals from returning safely, or in certain
> circumstances, where the country is unable to handle the return of its
> nationals adequately. USCIS may grant TPS to eligible nationals of
> certain countries (or parts of countries), who are already in the
> United States. Eligible individuals without nationality who last
> resided in the designated country may also be granted TPS.
>
> The Secretary may designate a country for TPS due to the following
> temporary conditions in the country:
>
> -Ongoing armed conflict (such as civil war)
>
> -An environmental disaster (such as earthquake or hurricane), or an epidemic
> -Other extraordinary and temporary conditions
>
> During a designated period, individuals who are TPS beneficiaries or who are found preliminarily eligible for TPS upon initial review of their cases (prima facie eligible):
>
> -Are not removable from the United States
>
> -Can obtain an employment authorization document (EAD) May be granted travel authorization
>
> -Once granted TPS, an individual also cannot be detained by DHS on the basis of his or her immigration status in the United States.
>
> TPS is a temporary benefit that does not lead to lawful permanent
> resident status or give any other immigration status. However,
> registration for TPS does not prevent you from:
>
> -Applying for nonimmigrant status
>
> -Filing for adjustment of status based
> on an immigrant petition
>
> -Applying for any other immigration benefit or protection for which you may be eligible
>
> -PLEASE NOTE: To be granted any other immigration benefit you must still meet all the eligibility
> requirements for that particular benefit.  An application for TPS does
> not affect an application for asylum or any other immigration benefit
> and vice versa. Denial of an application for asylum or any other
> immigration benefit does not affect your ability to register for TPS,
> although the grounds of denial of that application may also lead to
> denial of TPS.

Comment: For completeness, where did you apply from?

Comment: If they thought you were inadmissible, they would have denied your visa. So if you applied for and got a B2 visa after your TPS, what are you concerned about?

Comment: @user102008 the only concern is whether or not CBP officers have a harder time being satisfied about immigrant intent than consular officers

Comment: @Traveller from Austria

Comment: @Ozzy: Whether you have overcome the presumption of immigrant intent is subjective, and each officer can judge it differently, so this question can't really be answered.